# Does $2x^5+3x^{(a+1)/a}-b^2-4$ qualify as a Polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology

I am wondering if you could consider this expression a Polynomial.

$$2x^5+3x^{(a+1)/a}-b^2-4$$

My reason for asking is because the definition of a Polynomial says you cannot have variables in the denominator of the term, but if I recall correctly, you CAN have exponents with variables (I could be wrong though).

This question is taken from a French book that considers this example to be a Polynomial, and in fact it argues that it can be reduced to a monomial by equating the variables.

Is anyone familiar with this interpretation?

Comment: It is a polynomial in $x$ (if you consider $x$ to be the "variable"), but it is not a polynomial in $a$.

Comment: It is a polynomial in $x$ if $(a+1)/a$ is a nonnegative integer; otherwise it's not technically a polynomial.

Comment: I agree -- I would consider x to be the variable here.

Comment: Greg: right. And this is a point of contention for me. In the problem, they do not specify anything about the conditions for the exponent, so I find it is nebulous and too open to interpretation.

Comment: There are lots of unclear or thoughtless questions out in the world; there is no sense in worrying about whether this is "really" a polynomial, you should just endeavor in your own life to communicate your meaning clearly and unambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the following being a polynomial, correct?: $$2x^5+3x^{\frac{a+1}{a}}-b^2-4$$

Polynomials need positive (and whole number) exponents. So as long as $\frac{a+1}{a}$ is a positive whole number then it's a polynomial. We're also assuming this is a function of $x$ and $b$ is a constant (real number).

If $a=1$ then $\frac{a+1}{a}=2$ so we have a polynomial

If $a=2$ then $\frac{a+1}{a}=\color{red}{1.5}$ does not make the above a polynomial

Comment: I didn't know other people could edit answers, that's interesting

Comment: Yes, correct. The problem for me is that the example in the book only specifies that we should assume real numbers, but nothing else is said about the exponent, thus it's too broad and like you say, a = 1 would work, but a = 2 would not.

Comment: If they don't specify $a$ is an integer, then you can have $(a+1)/a=3$ or $a=0.5$, and your expression is still a polynomial. More general case, for $k\in\mathbb N, k\ge 2$, $a=\frac1{k-1}$ will yield a polynomial

Comment: You don't technically need $b$ a constant real number. It could be a polynomial over $\mathbb R[b]$ or some other commutative ring containing $b.$

Comment: @Andrei good point, I feel like I should know this, but how did you find that general case?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I only added that restriction because I wanted to limit my answer to what I know for sure.

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, letting $x=y^a$ we have a polynomial in $y$

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins just solve $(a+1)/a=k$, $a+1=ka$, $1=(k-1)a$, $x=1/(k-1)$. So $k$ can't be $1$